# str_split do not run vectorizely in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, stringr

**Context**

I have a `df`. I want to extract the air pollution name from the file name `x`.

I can extract air pollution name when the name in a character vector:

```r
library(tidyverse)

str_split('data/raw/air/CO/2013.txt', pattern = '/')[[1]][4]
#> [1] "CO"

str_split('data/raw/air/PM2.5/2013.txt', pattern = '/')[[1]][4]
#> [1] "PM2.5"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

But when the air pollution names is a variable named `x` in dataframe `df`, `str_split()` would give an unexpected result.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(x = c('data/raw/air/CO/2013.txt',
                       'data/raw/air/PM2.5/2013.txt'))

df %>% mutate(air = str_split(x, pattern = '/')[[1]][4])
#>                             x air
#> 1    data/raw/air/CO/2013.txt  CO
#> 2 data/raw/air/PM2.5/2013.txt  CO
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

**Quesiton**

1. Is str_split() not a vectorized function?
2. How can I extract air pollution name from the datafram `df`?

**Reproducible code**

```r
library(tidyverse)

# Expected results

str_split('data/raw/air/CO/2013.txt', pattern = '/')[[1]][4]

str_split('data/raw/air/PM2.5/2013.txt', pattern = '/')[[1]][4]

# Unexpected results

df <- data.frame(x = c('data/raw/air/CO/2013.txt',
                       'data/raw/air/PM2.5/2013.txt'))

df %>% mutate(air = str_split(x, pattern = '/')[[1]][4])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the moment you use `[[1]]` meansyou are only considering the first value and not the first value of each element. consider using `pluck/chuck` as shown below:

```
df %>%
   mutate(air = map_chr(str_split(x, pattern = '/'), chuck, 4))                        

                            x   air
1    data/raw/air/CO/2013.txt    CO
2 data/raw/air/PM2.5/2013.txt PM2.5
```